# how to join two subset (defined by one group variable) of the same table in sql

Tags: sql, join, sas, subset

I can write 3 separate procedures to achieve it. 2 procedures for getting each subset, and the 3rd procedure for join. Can this be done in one procedure?

```
proc sql;
create table a as select a.var1, a.var2
from study a
where studyid="A";
quit;

proc sql;
create table b as select a.var1, a.var2
from study a
where studyid="B";
quit;

proc sql;
create table combined as
select a.var1 AS match_id, a.var2 AS control, b.var2 AS treated
FROM a JOIN b ON
a.var1=b.var1;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in one query:

```
proc sql;
create table combined as
    select a.var1 AS match_id, a.var2 AS control, b.var2 AS treated
    from study a join
         study b
         on a.var1 = b.var1
    where a.studyid = 'A' and
          b.studyid = 'B';
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to learn more about SQL.

Comment: I already accepted but my reputation is too low to make the vote show publicly. Sorry about that.

Comment: @hehe . . . You can always *accept* an answer to a question that you ask regardless of your reputation.  You cannot upvote until you have a certain reputation.